# When we should use file.write(...) instead of file.createWriteStream(...)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, fs

What is the difference between `file.write(fd,...)` and `file.createWriteStream(...)` ?

E.g : in the following code , both of the snippets doing same thing.

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var newFile = fs.createWriteStream('newFile.txt');
    request.pipe(newFile);
});,

var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
http.createServer(function(request, response) {
    var data = "";
    request.on('data', function(chunk) {
        data += chunk.toString();
    });
    reuqest.on('end', function() {
        fs.write('newFile.txt', chunk);
    });
});
```

I'm confused between that which one is better ?! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When you are dealing with the binary data, the former approach is better. It will pipe the request stream directly to the file specified. Also using this approach, you won't have to deal with the memory issues which might arise had the incoming data size is large.

The second approach works in scenarios where one is just dealing with the text stream and character encoding is known. If the incoming data is part of some image, pdf etc. then you will receive buffer data and the second approach won't work properly. Also, according to [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefile_file_data_options_callback), it is unsafe to use `fs.write` multiple times on the same file without waiting for the callback and `fs.createWriteStream` is advised.